# Passing variable to class XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt-1.0

Need to set the counting variable in the for each of a row in the sorttable_customkey="" ...

```
<countNo><xsl:variable name="counting" select="position()"/></countNo>
<th width="150" align="left" scope="col" sorttable_customkey="['$counting']">
```

Please advise

Comment: You can evaluate variable values by using `<xsl:value-of select="$counting"/>`. Also, your question is not clear. Please post a detailed explanation of what you are trying to achieve and also the code you have written till now. Thanks.

Comment: Need to pass the <xsl:value-of select="$counting"/> into the value of the style of sorttable_customkey=

Comment: So it is like....   <th width="150" align="left" scope="col" sorttable_customkey="<xsl:value-of select="$counting"/>">